# Webtoon about a red-haired boy with magical powers

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

I'm helping a friend find a webtoon she read three years ago.

What she remembers is that the main character is a red-haired boy with magical powers, but is keeping it a secret. A black-haired boy who plays baseball finds out and keeps it a secret too. The red-haired boy also has a grandmother who who has magical powers too.

Edit:
More information

They wear modern clothes, his Magic he can make things float in the air, I think his pencil turns into a monster, his grandmother in real form is old,but in Magic form she's young and pretty. That's all my friend remembers so far

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been looking for the same one. It’s a webtoon called *[That Awkward Magic!!](https://www.webtoons.com/en/canvas/that-awkward-magic-/list?title_no=90731)*

> Hey you reader, I just want to say that before this shit, -can I say
> shit? No? It's ok, whatever- ...I was a normal high school guy with
> normal life and normal hobbies, until one day, thanks to weird events
> and a crazy ex-girlfriend, I met someone who changed my life. If you
> want to know how it happened... Well, you can subscribe to my life
>
> [image: Title card for "That Awkward Magic" by SomeBunny. A red-haired boy in a hoodie floats upwards while holding hands with a black-haired boy who has a pierced ear visible. Their hands are glowing blue.]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the webtoon the OP is looking for, specifying any plot points that match the description given in the question, and any that don't. It'd help other users decide how likely this answer is to be correct or not.